# Symfony Form only in backend

Tags: php, forms, symfony

How to make a Symfony form only to validate data in backend? The data is submitted using AJAX and I've created a form class corresponding to the data, but `$form->handleRequest($request);` does not submit it for some reason, the errors are empty and I have no info and no way of finding out what is wrong.
Changing handling to `$form->submit($request->request->all());` throws a type error saying that the data is null, which it is not.

Edit: to clarify - there is NO rendered HTML form! Only pure data coming in from a POST request.

Comment: Please include your code in the question

Comment: What code do you want to see? Any example form will do as long as you do not put it in a template and only submit the data from JS (for example, `jQuery.post('/action', {foo: 'bar'});`, and foo is a field in your Entity).

Comment: Maybe the code of your form class and the code of your controller action. There is surely something to improve or change if you have this problem.

Comment: If you want to manually submit your form, the `submit()` function should look like this:  `$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));`.  You should post your AJAX code because my guess is that you are not sending the data properly.  You shouldn't just post keys and values to your form, you should be creating a form and then serializing it in AJAX.  If you only want to send keys/values then you shouldn't be using forms at all for your validation.

Comment: There is no form to serialize in AJAX... That's what I thought; that using forms wasn't the right thing to do, but my colleague, who's teaching me Symfony, says I have to use them. I think I'm just going to tell him no.

Comment: Yeah, I mean at worst you could create a hidden form on the HTML side and submit it, but if you're not going to submit an actual form then there's no reason to treat it like one in Symfony.

Comment: Well, I've spend a day and a half trying to find ways to make a form work; my nerves are wrecked and it is obvious this is not worth it. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code should works to handle your form.

```
/**
 * Handles the creation form.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="demo_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 *
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    //This is optional. Do not do this check if you want to call the same action using a regular request.
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'You can access this only using Ajax!'), 400);
    }

    // Create the form
    $entity = new YourEntity();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    // Handle it using your request
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // If valid, persist and flush the newly created entity
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'Success!'), 200);
    }

    // Return the form with errors
    return new JsonResponse(array(
        'errors' => $form->getErrors(),
    ), 400);     
}
```

Comment: There is no rendered form, only AJAX data. God, everyone tries to stuff the form in a template...

Comment: Lol, it's really not evident using the informations given in your question. Also, the primary goal  and default usage of creating a form class is to render it and then, handle it. I've edited my answer to keep only what you need. If it's not the answer that you expect, you should add more informations and code in your question.

Comment: #1 - `createCreateForm` - no such method. #2 - if I use `$this->createForm($entity);`, it throws this: `Expected argument of type "string, Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormTypeInterface or Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface", "BakingBank\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\TournamentInstance" given`. But your code is nice and understandable, so +1 for that :)

Comment: #1 it's just an example ! The createcreateform is the place where you build your form, assuming you build it. I will not add this part , it's in the doc. #2 I really cannot help you more if you don't show your code ! Good luck

Comment: I see. Well, I had made a form, but it didn't work due to the fact that `$form->handleRequest($request);` did not submit it for whatever reason. I'm guessing there should be something else in the POSTed data that says that the form is being submitted, but what that is - no idea.

Comment: In any case, this is clearly not worth the effort, so I'm dropping the idea. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: No, that's the thing. `$form->getErrors()` => empty array. `$form->isSubmitted()` => false.

Comment: You can validate your data without use a form class, you use it only for validation

Comment: I know and I have it done, it's just that my colleague wanted me to use a form for this.

Comment: Add an example of your json data, maybe it's not the expected format for forms. Tomorrow I will inspect the request of a classic form and compare with yours, if there is something to do, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Don't bother. Like I said, I'm dropping the whole idea.